# Найти блоки по css свойству

Tags: css, jquery, html

Возникла необходимость с помощью jquery найти все блоки на странице, у которых в стилях есть background. Есть идеи как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самом jquery такой возможности нет, однако можно перебрать все элементы на странице и проверить наличие у них css свойства background.

```
$('*').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    if (element && element.css('background') && element.css('background') !== 'none'){
     console.log(element);
    }
});
```

соответственно в консоль упадут все элементы с непустым свойством background. jquery пустые свойства возвращает как 'none'

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.searchBG > div').each(function(){
  let isBackground = $(this).css('background-color');
  if(isBackground != 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')
  console.info($(this).attr('class')+' = '+isBackground);
});
```

```css
.searchBG > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.bla-1-bla {
  background: green;
}
.bla-s-bla {
  background: red;
}

.a2a-bla-bla {
  background: transparent;
}

.sd-bla-bla {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="searchBG">
  <div class="bla-bla-bla"></div>
  <div class="bla-1-bla"></div>
  <div class="a2a-bla-bla"></div>
  <div class="bla-bla-3"></div>
  <div class="ddsd-bla-bla"></div>
  <div class="bla-s-bla"></div>
  <div class="bla-ase-asd"></div>
  <div class="sd-bla-bla"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если речь про поиск бэкграунд-картинок то можно вот так:

обратите внимание на [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) это нативный аналог `jquery` метода `.css()`

он возвращает эффективный стиль элемента, а не то, что вписано в инлайн стиль

```js
$('*').filter(function(){
   return ~getComputedStyle(this).background.indexOf('url(')
}).each(function(){
  console.log(this)
})
```

```css
.with_bg {background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAP5JREFUeNpi/P//PwMlgImBQjDwBrCgC9jPfQGmGRkZZwIJY4b//88CwykdJHYwWYKwC37/+gXGv37+NI5yFzMG0TAxolzw4dUrBg5ubjD7DVDPj69fwWwILUfYgK+fPgJt/8HAysbOcB+o5/uXL0DbfzL8/vmTuED8/+//TKDiM98+f2J4CDQARIP4IHGiDPjx7dvhb58+M1jEOhs//MbAoBPpbAzig8SxOgGUEpExl1EEA6dzTQx35JIzOgf//wfRID5IHF0tOBVjCECAArNJagmL/6wzIBrI1wFiNmwGMKLnBWD8gygBIOZCEv4DxG+Bav+i+4Bx6GcmgAADAAiPsgkULyM8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="with_bg">1</div>
<div class="no_bg">2</div>
<div class="with_bg">3</div>
<div class="no_bg">4</div>
```

Вот чисто на Jquery:

```js
$('*').filter(function(){
   return ~$(this).css('background').indexOf('url(');
}).each(function(){
  console.log(this)
})
```

```css
.with_bg {background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAP5JREFUeNpi/P//PwMlgImBQjDwBrCgC9jPfQGmGRkZZwIJY4b//88CwykdJHYwWYKwC37/+gXGv37+NI5yFzMG0TAxolzw4dUrBg5ubjD7DVDPj69fwWwILUfYgK+fPgJt/8HAysbOcB+o5/uXL0DbfzL8/vmTuED8/+//TKDiM98+f2J4CDQARIP4IHGiDPjx7dvhb58+M1jEOhs//MbAoBPpbAzig8SxOgGUEpExl1EEA6dzTQx35JIzOgf//wfRID5IHF0tOBVjCECAArNJagmL/6wzIBrI1wFiNmwGMKLnBWD8gygBIOZCEv4DxG+Bav+i+4Bx6GcmgAADAAiPsgkULyM8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="with_bg">1</div>
<div class="no_bg">2</div>
<div class="with_bg">3</div>
<div class="no_bg">4</div>
```